# File names are contaminated with '?' (ASCII 0x3F) and how to do with it

Tags: filenames

I'm a Japanese hobby programmer (using Embarcadero C++ Compiler (BCC102) in  Windows 10) and I face with some difficulties.

As everyone does, I have a lot of image files (mostly "*.jpg") and I update and rename the files by using date data (in such Japanese format as "YYYY年MM月DD日") of "Date of Creation" that appears in "Property Dialog" of the files (by use of right mouse click).

Later, when I came up with fatal errors using GDI+, I found that the file names as created in the manner as said above are in fact formatted "?YYYY?年?MM?月?DD?日", namely number characters are sandwiched by '?' (ASCII Code 0x3F), that is, by "taboo characters". I delved into the error by `GetLastError` function to see the error code was 123 or `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`.

I checked with each and every Japanese site to see what exactly have happened, how come Windows uses such codes for what purpose and why Windows can deal with filenames with such "taboo characters" without errors. It was just in vain. Nothing found.

If you (in any other part of the world than Japan) have experienced same or similar phenomena and found any piece of wisdom, I would really appreciate sharing such.

Comment: Yikes! I'm not familiar with Embarcadero C++ but (BCC102) sounds a lot like *Borland Compiler Collection* -- last updated in 1996.  That brings in a number of questions on windows with character encoding, character set and the good old 8.3 DOS filename verses the windows long-filename support. You will need to provide a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before anyone can help for sure. If you are on windows and want a compiler, why not VS-2022 Community (damn good) or MinGW (also damn good) -- Both Free...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Embarcadero C++ is continuation of Borland C++ Builder, itself a follow-up to the Borland C++ compiler, so it’s no wonder the names are similar. Pretty up-to-date too. No need to advocate for other compilers just because it’s not *your* favourite.

Comment: @user3840170 -- thank you. I do recall BCC being ? open-sourced or renamed, but didn't know to what, and didn't know that the old BCC code was updated in any way. That's good info. Borland wasn't a bad compiler, but was from the time that `string.h` was included in C++ `:)`